# Nav goes whole way down webpage and displays between elements. What do?

Tags: html, css

[as you can see the red nav seems to poke out between elements, it looks terrible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FMep.png)

How can I fix this? I've been doing web dev for a week so hoping a veteran can help!

If anybody wants to see the code just ask, I'm having problem posting it directly on here..

Thanks

Comment: The nav seems fine?Please do post your code, if not directly, via a JSFIDDLE.

Comment: @PaaPoo are you going to add css3 in all the questions

Answer (score 1):

In your case to bring nav in front of all the elements you can give it `z-index:-1` and `position:relative`.

Also refer to this fiddle.Hope it may help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/Xb2UT/4/